# Unable to retrieve certain pages using stringWithContentsOfURL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsurl

I am trying to get HTML files from the web, using `stringWithContentsOfURL:`. My problem is, sometimes it works but sometimes it doesn't. For example, I tried:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:
                               [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"] 
                                            encoding:encoding1 
                                               error:nil];

NSLog(@"html = %@",string);
```

This works fine, but when I replace the URL with `@"http://www.youtube.com/"` then I only get "NULL". Is there anyone that knows what's going on? Is it because of YouTube having some sort of protection?

Comment: What other URL's have you tried? It could be a loading delay.

Answer (score 4):

Google's home page uses ISO-8859-1 encoding (aka "Latin-1", or `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`). YouTube uses UTF-8 (`NSUTF8StringEncoding`), and the encoding you've specified with your `encoding1` variable has to match the web page in question.

If you just want the web page and don't really care what encoding it's in, try this:

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSError *error;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:
                               [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"] 
                                       usedEncoding:&encoding
                                              error:&error];

NSLog(@"html = %@",string);
```

This method will tell you what the encoding was (by writing it to the `encoding` variable), but you can just throw that away and focus on the string.

Comment: `NSStringEncoding` is a `typedef` to `NSUInteger`. Shouldn't the first line be `NSStringEncoding encoding;`?

Comment: Wow, that typo lasted for 18 months. Fixed.